# applying conditionally css class on input element

Tags: css, angularjs

I have an input field where I want conditionally apply CSS class.

For example if `firstName == undefined` apply CSS class `ng-dirty`. So, I tried

```
<input required [(ngModel)]="customer.firstName" name="firstName"           
       type="text" minlength="2" maxlength="50" ng-class="{ng-dirty : customer.firstName === undefined}">
```

that however doesn't work.

Comment: Add your controller code as well as some extra html code.

Comment: which version of angular are you using. because tag shows angularjs but your code seems to use angular 4. both. Be specific about the version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Angular 2/ Angular 4 the below is the conditional syntax for NgClass

```
<some-element [ngClass]="{'first': true, 'second': true, 'third': false}">...</some-element>
```

and if You are using angularJs(i.e. angular 1.x) use below

```
<some-element ng-class="{'fist' : true, 'second': true}">...</some-element>
```

[Official Docs for Angular4 [NgClass]](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)

[Official DOcs for AngularJS ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
<input required [(ngModel)]="customer.firstName" name="firstName"           
       type="text" minlength="2" maxlength="50" [class]="(customer.firstName == undefined) ? 'dirty' : ''" >
```

But I don't think **customer.firstName** will ever be undefined, since you defined it when you put it in the model.

Answer (score 0):

Js object notation can't have - dashes all you need is a quote to make it happen

```
<input required [(ngModel)]="customer.firstName" name="firstName"           
   type="text" minlength="2" maxlength="50" ng-class="{'ng-dirty' : customer.firstName === undefined}">
```